# Quick way to replace any occurrence of zero in a list with one while iterating (python)

Tags: python

How do I replace the 0 value in the the list below with one, to avoid division error?

```
_list=[0,1,2,3]
n=[]
for x in _list:
    if x ==0:
        print 1
    else:
        div=2.0/x
        n.append(div)
```

I would like the new value (1) to partake in the division.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `div = 2.0/x` but not `div = x/2.0`

Comment: Hi John, in my actual data, I will encounter division by zero. The inverse of my desired output is what will be relevant to me

Comment: Improve your question, if you can

Comment: @Tiger1: Yeah, if you just change it to `div = 2.0/x` as Grijesh Chauhan suggests, it'll be a better demonstration of the problem, because it'll be more obvious what you want and why.

Comment: @abarnert, you are  right, I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it. The problem is that you're just `print`ing the 1, instead of using it in place of the 0. So:

```
_list=[0,1,2,3]
n=[]
for x in _list:
    if x ==0:
        x=1
    div=x/2.0
    n.append(div)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its exactly what I was trying to craft out.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
[x/2.0 if x else None for x in _list]
=> [None, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
```

The above list comprehension will return a list with the divisions, with a `None` where the `0/2` division occurs. Or this:

```
[x/2.0 for x in _list if x]
=> [0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
```

The above avoids the value with the `0/2` division; pick the one that makes more sense for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
_list=[0,1,2,3]
print [num/2.0 if num else 0.5 for num in _list]
```

**Output**

```
[0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is replace 0 with 1 in _list, all you need to do is change your if statement. Instead of if x == 0: print 1, you need:

```
for x in _list:
    if x ==0:
        x == 1
```